# There Is No Row At Position 5

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

I'm Using C Sharp

I Get This error after running the debugger to see wat is wrong with the code:

{"There is no row at position 5."}  System.Exception {System.IndexOutOfRangeException}

```
   public DataSet FindData(string ID, string pass)
    {
        InitializeConnection();
        m_oCn.Open();
        DataSet thisDataSet = new DataSet();
        DataSet foundDataSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            m_oDA.Fill (thisDataSet, "Login");
            for (int n = 0; 0 < thisDataSet.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count ; n++)
            {
                if (thisDataSet.Tables["Login"].Rows[n]["UserName"].ToString () == ID)
                {
                    if (thisDataSet.Tables["Login"].Rows[n]["Password"].ToString () == pass)
                    {
                        m_oDA.Fill(foundDataSet,n,1,"Login");


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            m_oCn.Close();
            m_oCn = null;
        }
        return foundDataSet;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int n = 0; 0 < thisDataSet.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count; n++)
```

Your for loop's condition checks if zero is less than the row count, which means that your loop will run indefinitely (or until you access a non-existent index).  You probably mean to check if `n` is less than the row count:

```
for (int n = 0; n < thisDataSet.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count; n++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop if flawed:

```
for (int n = 0; 0 < thisDataSet.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count ; n++)
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
for (int n = 0; n < thisDataSet.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count ; n++)
```